# React new project does not re compile on save

Tags: reactjs, websocket, compilation, rendering

I've created a new react app using `create-react-app`. running `npm start` compile the app and opens the hello react page on localhost://3000, but any change to the project and saving nothing happens.

in the chrome console there is the following error:

> **Error handling response: Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws/ws' is invalid.**
> at init (chrome-extension://fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/reload.js:22:18)
> at chrome-extension://fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/reload.js:65:13
> I'm using Visual studio on Macbook

npm version 6.14.8

node version 14.15.1

react version 17.0.1

(Angular cli project re-compile without a problem)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Deleting the app and running create-react-app again solved the problem.
The initial screen looks different though - so maybe it was a version compatibility issue.